# Why is openpyxl.load_workbook not working?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to edit a spreadsheet that already exists with openpyxl, and I read that load_workbook should do it, but it gave me a strange error saying that it could not decode certain bytes.

My code:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\Users\asher\Downloads\West Lake Sammamish addresses.xlsm")
```

The error message said "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"

Comment: You need to change your path string. Python is interpreting the '\U' in 'C:\Users' as Unicode and could similarly interpret other sections in the string where backslash exists as other 'escape sequences'. It can work if there are no interpreted escape sequences in the path but any part of a string read as `\X` which is an escape sequence will be interpreted as such. If you want to use a standard Windows path with backslashes you must set it as a raw string by placing an 'r' in front of the string or delimit the backslashes or use forward slashes instead.

Comment: Any of these following methods can be used; Raw String:- `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\asher\Downloads\West Lake Sammamish addresses.xlsm")` . Delimit the backslashes with another backslash:- `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\asher\\Downloads\\West Lake Sammamish addresses.xlsm")` . Use forward slash instead `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/asher/Downloads/West Lake Sammamish addresses.xlsm")`. Forward slash can be used with any Operating System